# Python pandas read data of the form Label <index_1>:<val_1> <index_2>:<val_2>

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, kaggle

For example, a row in the data looks like this

```
-1 0:183.3575741549828 1:3.11164735151736 2:2.171277907851733 3:26.68849990272964 4:24.76677388937082 5:0.02710337995527495
```

The reason why index is specified is because attributes for which index is not specified are assumed to be zero.

I'm trying to use the statement:

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=None, delim_whitespace=True).values
```

It is showing the following error:

> train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=None, delim_whitespace=True).values
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 401, in _read
>       data = parser.read()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 939, in read
>       ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1508, in read
>       data = self._reader.read(nrows)
>
> File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 848, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:10415)
>
> File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 870, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:10691)
>
> File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 924, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:11437)
>
> File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 911, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:11308)
>
> File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 2024, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:27037)
>
> pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 132 fields in line 5, saw 143

I can't seem to figure out the problem here. Any help would be great!

Comment: can you please edit your error into readable format? Also, I cannot undertand the row in your data. Is that a row of dictionaries?

Comment: @splinter
This is a line in a csv file. The number of attributes is a fixed number say, 4125 (0-4124). A row specifies the values of attributes for a training example, 2:1231 says attribute 2 is 1231

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data description and the error message my guess is that the rows in your csv file do not have the same amount of fields per row. Try specifying the field columns:

```
my_cols = range(0,4125)
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names=my_cols).values
```

Find more help here: [import csv with different number of columns per row using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020216/import-csv-with-different-number-of-columns-per-row-using-pandas) and here: [Handling Variable Number of Columns with Pandas - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242746/handling-variable-number-of-columns-with-pandas-python)

Comment: Did this resolve your problem or do you need further help?