# Pandas read_csv create columns based on maxmimum number of delimiters in a row

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a (badly formed) csv like this:

```
header1, header2, header3
value1, value2, value3, value4
```

I'd like to load this into a dataframe. However

```
pd.read_csv(file_data, index = False)
```

drops value4:

| header1 | header2 | header3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | value3 |

and

```
pd.read_csv(file_data)
```

leaves me with no way to differentiate if the value of the index came from value1 in the csv file, or was autoassigned by pandas.

Is there a way to have pandas just create dummy columns on the end based on the row with the maximum number of delimiters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import csv with different number of columns per row using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020216/import-csv-with-different-number-of-columns-per-row-using-pandas)

Comment: @Gusti Adli's response below seemed the most elegant, as at least several of the top comments on that thread imply that the user knows the maximum number of columns beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is only the header, setting the header `parameter` as `None` will solve your problem.

```
pd.read_csv(file_data, header=None)
```

If the number of delimiters on each row is different, you need to read each line using `open()` function.

```
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    df = [i.strip().split(',') for i in f.readlines()]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)
```

Output: (I added `"1,2,3,4,5,6\n"` and `"11,22,33\n"` after the last row)

```
         0        1        2       3     4     5
0  header1  header2  header3          None  None
1   value1   value2   value3  value4  None  None
2        1        2        3       4     5     6
3       11       12       13    None  None  None
```