# Convert awkwardly formatted data into a dataframe with pandas python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have some data in the following csv format:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Variable 1 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| Time | Value |  |  |
| Time1 | 12 |  |  |
| Time2 | 32 |  |  |
| Time3 | 4 |  |  |
| Time4 | 5 |  |  |
| Time5 | 34 |  |  |
| Time6 | 5 |  |  |
| Time7 | 46 |  |  |
| Time8 | 7 |  |  |
| Time9 | 8 |  |  |
| Time10 | 543 |  |  |
| Variable 2 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| Time | Value |  |  |
| Time1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Time2 | 2 | 45 | 5 |
| Time3 | 4 | 2 | 54 |
| Time4 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| Time5 | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| Time6 | 4 | 5 | 8 |
| Time7 | 4 | 7 | 4 |
| Time8 | 8 | 65 | 12 |
| Time9 | 12 | 8 | 14 |
| Time10 | 65 | 65 | 13 |
| Variable 3 |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| Time | Value |  |  |
| Time1 | 3 |  |  |
| Time2 | 4 |  |  |
| Time3 | 5 |  |  |
| Time4 | 2 |  |  |
| Time5 | 1 |  |  |
| Time6 | 7 |  |  |
| Time7 | 5 |  |  |
| Time8 | 3 |  |  |
| Time9 | 5 |  |  |
| Time10 | 7 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

And want to put it in the following data frame format with pandas:

```
         Variable1    Variable2    Variable3    
Time1           12     [1,2,3]             3
Time2           32    [2,45,5]             4
Time3            4    [4,2,54]             5
```

How would I even go about this? I know the format is awful, don't ask me why it's like that but I'm kinda stuck with it. I really don't even know where to begin with this one. TIA

Comment: Load it into temporary DF, Dropna in Col1, later, add new column and if Col1 has string `Variable*`, copy cell value to the nwe column, - later fffill down the column, the rest is just pivot or unstack and etc.

Comment: Is this data a single file or several?

Comment: Same file, it looks like this: https://easyupload.io/bdxtlo

Comment: check it in .txt format and try importing data frame from .txt, - looks way easier

Comment: same error: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 36, saw 91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated code as per comments

initial file read is based on code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020216/import-csv-with-different-number-of-columns-per-row-using-pandas/57824142#57824142):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = r'C:\Test\TIMBER-1100-10M.csv'
# Loop the data lines
with open(file, 'r') as temp_f:
    # get No of columns in each line
    col_count = [ len(l.split(",")) for l in temp_f.readlines() ]

# Generate column names  (names will be 0, 1, 2, ..., maximum columns - 1)
column_names = [i for i in range(0, max(col_count))]
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, delimiter=",", names=column_names)

# preparing dataframe for pivot
df['Variable'] = np.where(df[0].str.contains('VARIABLE:'), df[0], np.nan)
df['Variable'].ffill(inplace=True)
df[1].dropna(inplace=True)
drop_values = ['Timestamp','VARIABLE:']
df2 = df[~df[0].str.contains('|'.join(drop_values))].astype({col: str for col in df.columns[2:]})

conc_col = df2.columns.to_list()
conc_col.remove(0)
conc_col.remove('Variable')

df2['Value'] = df2[conc_col].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1).str.strip(',nan')
df2.rename(columns={ df.columns[0]: "Time" }, inplace = True)

# creating the pivot as final dataframe
pivot = df2.pivot_table(index=['Time'],
                        columns=['Variable'],
                        values='Value',
                        aggfunc='sum')\
                        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)\
                        .reset_index()
pivot.to_excel(r'C:\Test\temp1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the data underneath is the following blocks variable name, ie the title of the data frame column.

Running that gives me: TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on_bad_lines'

Comment: not sure why you get the error, maybe update the above question with your code, as pandas docs https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html do have parameter `on_bad_lines='skip'`

Comment: Yup, apparently we are stuck using pandas 1.2.2 which does not have this feature.

Comment: as per docs, try the old pandas param: `, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False` 
instead of one `on_bad_lines='skip'`

Comment: updated my answer, - just in case

Comment: Okay yea that works with my version. The result is close but its missing the titles and is just a 2 column data frame, it needs a column for each variable. I'm starting to think this is impossible and I need to come up with something different. I am having no luck either.

Comment: this option made it work for the start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020216/import-csv-with-different-number-of-columns-per-row-using-pandas/57824142#57824142

Comment: and the rest, as per my very first comment.

Comment: Yeah this is the closest I got too, I used a different method: `df = pd.read_csv('TIMBER-1100-10M_easy.csv', header=None, sep='\n')
df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)` but it's still not quite there

Comment: Although the one you linked is better because that gives me NaNs instead of None throughout my df, but it still doesn't have the correct column names, but I think I might be able to go from the linked df to the correct one and post the solution, thanks!

Comment: Actually I was wrong, that's no where near the solution I need.

Comment: the linked code gives a quite nice starting dataframe, the rest is just small adjustments and pivot, I can try to write the full solution, if you will explain how you want to treat the bottom line as it has 89 duplicated values in the `Array Values` column and only 2  unique

Comment: Updated the code above as per comments