# How to read csv files with different amounts of columns using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, glob

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("Data/*.csv")
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in files))
print(df)
```

I get an error that says: "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 39 fields in line 273, saw 40". Then as per this question: [import csv with different number of columns per row using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020216/import-csv-with-different-number-of-columns-per-row-using-pandas) , I tried passing in the names of the columns, using StringIO
and BytesIO, then I got errors like: "TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not list" or "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'". I am looking at over 20 csv files.

Comment: have you tried this answer in the link you mentioned?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52890095/8805842
it should work

Comment: It expects a string, not a list

Comment: I guess, sharing the example file is the only solution...
chop it a bit to smaller size (or remove any private data and hope pandaNinjas will be interested

Comment: @NoobVB, here's the example data https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/stormevents/listevents.jsp?eventType=%28C%29+Tornado&beginDate_mm=12&beginDate_dd=01&beginDate_yyyy=1999&endDate_mm=12&endDate_dd=31&endDate_yyyy=1999&hailfilter=0.00&tornfilter=0&windfilter=000&sort=DT&submitbutton=Search&statefips=-999%2CALL , I am downloading csv's from 1990 to 1999

Comment: I have managed to find year 1999 only...

Comment: Can you narrow down to **which particular file/date it fails?** It is a particular thing from _that_ file. Maybe you can upload that one. Year 1999 imports fine for me.

Comment: Year 1999 by itself works fine for me too, but i have downloaded 10 years of data. For example, year 1990 has different columns. I cant tell exactly which year it fails on because I have many csv files.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have not tried all solutions as you actually had an answer in the link you shared:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57824142/8805842
if you inspect the last row/last column cell in your .csv file you will see why you get error.

Solution (simple copy/paste from your question link) with 2 more rows to remove unwanted/empty columns

```
    ### Loop the data lines
    with open("storm_data_search_results.csv", 'r') as temp_f:
        # get No of columns in each line
        col_count = [ len(l.split(",")) for l in temp_f.readlines() ]
    
    ### Generate column names  (names will be 0, 1, 2, ..., maximum columns - 1)
    column_names = [i for i in range(0, max(col_count))]
    
    ### Read csv
    df = pd.read_csv("storm_data_search_results.csv", header=None, delimiter=",", names=column_names)
    
    # my addition
    df.columns = df.iloc[0] # create headers from the first row
    df = df.iloc[:, 0:39] # keeping data frame with named headers only
```

**Update**
OMG,
be careful... the data they give in .csv actually is not structured properly.... just scroll all it down...
if you can use any other source, - use it, Unless you do not need "comments" and you can drop them.

Comment: what do you mean by "scroll all it down"?

Comment: @Michael, what he means is - load the CSV into a text editor and look at it.  It is not a well-formed CSV.  The problem is in 1998 data.

Comment: Also problem in 1997 data

Comment: I tried what @NoobVB did and I got the error: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the problem comes from the text fields that are multiline and can easily get messed up...
...you can remove them using RegEx: `re.subn(r'(".*?")',"_______________",xx,xx.count('"'), re.DOTALL)`

Also, assuming constant headers in all files, you can process all in text and then parse once.

```
# Read headers
headers = open(files[0]).read().split('\n',1)[0].split(',')

# Read all files and remove headers
xx = [open(ff).read().split('\n',1)[1] for ff in files]

# Remove the comments fields
dd = [re.sub(r'(".*?")',"__",x,x.count('"'), re.DOTALL) for x in xx]

# Load as CSV
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(''.join(dd), names = headers)
```