# How to group data by count of columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with a lot of rows and different number of columns.

How to group data by count of columns and show it in different frames?

File CSV has the following data:

```
1 OLEG US FRANCE BIG
1 OLEG FR 18
1 NATA 18
```

Because I have different number of colums in each row I have to group  rows by count of columns and show 3 frames to be able set header then:

```
        ID NAME  STATE COUNTRY HOBBY 
   FR1: 1  OLEG    US   FRANCE  BIG

        ID NAME  COUNTRY AGE
   FR2: 1   OLEG   FR    18


  FR3:  
     ID  NAME AGE
     1  NATA    18
```

Any words, I need to group rows by count of columns and show them in different dataframes.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately your question is not very clear. Please have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing sample input, expected output, and code for what you've tried so far based on your own research. This will help us better understand how to help you

Comment: I have added some details

Comment: pandas doesn't tolerate variable-width rows, so it's not obvious to us what your dataframe looks like. Can you show us the code you have so far, and the results of `print(df)` at the point that you'd like to do this? That would help us understand where you're starting from.

Comment: I showed the data in question it is three lines with different number of colums. For each column I have to determine the column name

Comment: The same question is here: https://discuss.dizzycoding.com/import-csv-with-different-number-of-columns-per-row-using-pandas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since pandas doesn't allow you to have different length of columns, just don't use it to import your data. Your goal is to create three seperate `df`, so first import the data as lists, and then deal with it and its differents lengths.

One way to solve this is read the data with `csv.reader` and create the `df's` with list comprehension together with a condition for the length of the lists.

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    data= list(reader)
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame([item for item in data if len(item)==3], columns='ID NAME AGE'.split())
df2 = pd.DataFrame([item for item in data if len(item)==4], columns='ID NAME COUNTRY AGE'.split())
df3 = pd.DataFrame([item for item in data if len(item)==5], columns='ID NAME STATE COUNTRY HOBBY'.split())
    
print(df1, df2, df3, sep='\n\n')

  ID  NAME AGE
0  1  NATA  18

  ID  NAME COUNTRY AGE
0  1  OLEG      FR  18

  ID  NAME STATE COUNTRY HOBBY
0  1  OLEG    US  FRANCE   BIG
```

If you need to hardcode too many lines for the same step (e.g. too many `df's`), then you should consider using a loop to create them and store each dataframe as key/value in a dictionary.

**EDIT**
Here is the little optimizedway of creating those `df's`. I think you can't get around creating a list of columns you want to use for the seperate `df's`, so you need to know what variations of number of columns you have in your data (except you want to create those `df's` without naming the columns.

```
col_list=[['ID', 'NAME', 'AGE'],['ID', 'NAME', 'COUNTRY', 'AGE'],['ID', 'NAME', 'STATE', 'COUNTRY', 'HOBBY']]

with open('input.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    data= list(reader)

dict_of_dfs = {}
for cols in col_list:
    dict_of_dfs[f'df_{len(cols)}'] = pd.DataFrame([item for item in data if len(item)==len(cols)], columns=cols)
    
for key,val in dict_of_dfs.items():
    print(f'{key=}: \n {val} \n')

key='df_3': 
   ID  NAME AGE
0  1  NATA  18 

key='df_4': 
   ID  NAME COUNTRY AGE
0  1  OLEG      FR  18 

key='df_5': 
   ID  NAME STATE COUNTRY HOBBY
0  1  OLEG    US  FRANCE   BIG
```

Now you don't have variables for your `df`, instead you have them in a dictionary as keys. (I named the `df` with the number of columns it has, `df_3` is the `df` with three columns.

If you need to import the data with pandas, you could have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020216/import-csv-with-different-number-of-columns-per-row-using-pandas).

Comment: is it possible to open and read file using Pandas and I has issue with three the same loops. How to optimize this?

Comment: Thank you! How create a set of lines by columns count?

Comment: what do you mean by that ?